# Prestashop v.1.4.8.2 Accessing Context Fatal Error PHP

Tags: php, prestashop, google-ads-api

I'm trying to populate an AdWords tag from Google in the Prestashop shopping-cart. On my mirror stage server this line worked fine; on the live server it fails.

```
$context = new Context();
$cart = new Cart($context->cookie->id_cart);
```

in /var/www/override/classes/FrontController.php

fails with:

> Fatal error: Class 'Context' not found in
>   /var/www/override/classes/FrontController.php on line 67

I also tried `$context = Context::getContext();` but also no success.

I need all the Products in the shopping cart in order to set their ids in the tag.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Context class was introduced in Prestashop 1.5 so with the 1.4 you won't be able to use it. You need to find another way!

Not tested but this should work

```
global $cookie;

$cart = new Cart((int)$cookie->id_cart);
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I still can't figure out why the $context command worked on my other 1.4 server. Very interessting.